# BigDecimal in android api 16

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal, android-api-levels

I'm new to Android so please, explain me, how to use BigDecimal in API level 16, because using this line:

```
BigDecimal currentNumber = new BigDecimal(String "0.0");
```

results in an error, Call requires api level 24.

Comment: Why not just upgrade to 24?

Comment: Probably, because Samsung didn't make any updates for Galaxy Note 2 for years, so it runs Android 4.4. Making an app, that I can't use would be kind of dumb.

Comment: I dont see what you mean. Android uses java. You can just use normal strings and bigdecimals independant of your api level I think. Make sure you are not using any jdk 7 features and some jdk 6 features are only supported after lvl 19. But bigdecimal is jdk 5

Comment: Also you have a syntac error as far as I can tell. leave the "String" out or use new String("0.0").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are constructing the object wrong...
BigDecimal is available since [API1](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

you need to do:

```
BigDecimal currentNumber = new BigDecimal("0.0");
```

Note that I removed the unnecessary **String** Class just pass the value between quotes...

Comment: Still says, that API 24 is needed.

Comment: Maybe there is a way, to set a specific version of BigDecimal?

Comment: API 24 is not needed to use BigDecimal. Where does it state that it needs API 24? The IDE gives you that error while compiling that line?

Comment: It worked, but with a small addition. When I initially started this project, I made a mistake of choosing the target SDK version to 24. After I changed it to 16, everything worked.

Comment: fernandospr, When I was writing the code, it highlighted the "new BigDecimal("0.0");" part as an error, when I hover the cursor over, it showed: Call requires api level 24.

Answer (score 5):

import this

```
java.math.BigDecima(Added in API 1)
```

instead of this

```
android.icu.math.BigDecimal(Added in API 24)
```